# DataFrame indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```py
area = pd.Series({'California': 423967, 'Texas': 695662,
                  'Florida': 170312, 'New York': 141297,
                  'Pennsylvania': 119280})
pop = pd.Series({'California': 39538223, 'Texas': 29145505,
                 'Florida': 21538187, 'New York': 20201249,
                 'Pennsylvania': 13002700})
data = pd.DataFrame({'area':area, 'pop':pop})
data['density'] = data.pop / data.area
```

`data['Florida':'New York']['pop':'area']` or `data['Florida':'New York']['area':]` print   area    pop density
without values

I tried to dealing with implicit indexes it is valid and `data['Florida':'New York'][:'area']` is valid and its output is the first two row with all columns with values and I can't understand why ????

Comment: "`data['Florida':'New York'][:'area']` is valid and its output is the first two row with all columns."  Are you sure you didn't type `data['Florida':'New York']['area':]`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to read the asking guide to get better help faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

For grabbing DataFrame slices, and not just individual columns, it's generally recommended to stay away from multiple levels of brackets.

Luckily Pandas has a better alternative, namely `.loc[row_slice, column_slice]`

If I understood your question correctly, you wish to obtain a slice containing all values between Florida and New york in your DataFrame, including all values after area.

The following code achieves this goal:

```py
# First we initiate the DataFrame as you've described it.
area = pd.Series({'California': 423967, 'Texas': 695662, 'Florida': 170312, 'New York': 141297, 'Pennsylvania': 119280})
pop = pd.Series({'California': 39538223, 'Texas': 29145505, 'Florida': 21538187, 'New York': 20201249, 'Pennsylvania': 13002700})
data = pd.DataFrame({'area':area, 'pop':pop})

# Next we find the density.
data['density'] = data['pop'] / data['area']

#Finally we obtain a slice.
data.loc['Florida':'New York', 'area':]
```

As all rows are after `'area'` we don't actually require that slice in this query, thus `data.loc['Florida':'New York']` would give an equivalent result.